# odoo15 enterprise edition installation in Linux VPS server

Tags: odoo-enterprise, odoo-15

I am trying to install odoo15 enterprise edition on a Linux VPS server , But I'm facing many issues during installation .

Can you guys help me with a clear guidelines about the installation process?

Comment: what did you do? what are the errors? please add them to your question, also read this article [mre] about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement. Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Ubuntu server, you can use an installation script to easily install Odoo.

You can find an installation script from Yenthe over [here](https://github.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript)

I have a slightly modified version of the same script over [here](https://github.com/mihranThalhath/installScript/)